# Is it possible to change color in web.CalendarRenderer?

Tags: css, odoo-12

Is it possible to assign colors to a certain event state as default? (Calendar)

I.e. Ocupied is red / available is green / no-show is blue / ready to start is yellow...

right now odoo as default color for 1st event, 2nd event is another color.. i want by state! is it possible and how? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any different class for different events like, occupied, available, no-show, ready-to-start..

Comment: i dont think so..
Is it possible to change the colors that odoo assigns to the events, to the colors we want?

If so, how do you it? It's only needed to change the css color assignment, or do we have to change js funtion _getColor()?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we need different class for different events.. so we have to add the background color,  depends on the classes..

Comment: Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Ya, i know to add a background color for each class.. Do u have a code for each event? If yes,  then add the class for each and every event..